# siunitx: How to homogeneously color rows of manually separated S columns?

Tags: tables, color, tabularx, siunitx

I would like to control the spacing between the `siunitx` columns, however, the insertion of `!{\hspace{1ex}}` between the third and fourth columns results in the discontinuity of the gray color in the third row,

[image]

while `<{\hspace{1ex}}` doesn't have any effect on the output.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx,siunitx,multicol,ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\Centering}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedLeft}X}

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{}
    \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{
            >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}L<{\hspace{1ex}}
            >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}Y<{\hspace{1ex}}
            S[table-format=3.1, round-precision=1, table-column-width = 0.2\linewidth, table-number-alignment=right]<{\hspace{1ex}}
            s[table-unit-alignment = left, table-column-width = 0.2\linewidth]
        }
        Parameter & Symbol & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Value}\\
        Inertia  & $J_M$ & 0.6 & \kilogram\m\squared\\
        Inertia  & $J_M$ & 0.6 & \kilogram\m\squared\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is because the \hspace{1ex} is added in replacement  of `|` to the normal `\tabcolsep`, and  the left and right colour overhangs in each column defaults to `\tabcolsep`. If you really need to use the  `!{...}` syntax, I think it might done with `!{\color{gray!10}\vrule width 1ex}` and playing with `\hhline` and `arrayrulecolor`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for your consideration. I have an off-topic question if you don't mind: how can I have tabularx environment with different column separation? For example, in my question, I need to inject some spacing of `\hspace{2ex}` between the first and the second columns. It seems that `<{\hspace{1ex}` is not the proper way.

Comment: 2ex between the 1st and 2nd columns, default separation between 2nd and  3rd and 1ex between 3rd and 4th? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @Bernard I found out that `<{\hspace{1ex}}` doesn't have any effect on the output. So, I need to globally set the separation to be `0ex` while injecting some space of `2ex` between the first and the second columns; is this possible?

Comment: I need to know if this will be valid for all columns separating space or only for the 1st and 2nd The solutions, if any, might differ.

Comment: @Bernard Only the first and second columns will have this extra space.

Comment: @Bernard For example, I need to fix [this document](https://pastebin.com/BqPGcXJi) to get rid of [this ugly output](https://i.ibb.co/qgHhQDN/image.png).

Comment: I've added an answer hopefully corresponding to what you want. Is it OK for you?

Comment: If the unit is always the same, why not put it into the header of  the corrensponding clumn instead of repeating it over and over?

Comment: @leandriis It is just an MWE not my real document `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `S` type columns you can use the key `table-space-text-post` to enlarge them to the right instead of `<{\hspace{1ex}}` (which puts `\hspace{1ex}` after the contents of a cell):

```latex
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx,siunitx,multicol,ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\Centering}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedLeft}X}

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{}
    \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{
            >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}L<{\hspace{1ex}}
            >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}Y<{\hspace{1ex}}
            S[table-format=3.1, round-precision=1, table-column-width = 0.2\linewidth, table-number-alignment=right, table-space-text-post=\hspace{1ex}]
            s[table-unit-alignment = left, table-column-width = 0.2\linewidth]
        }
        Parameter & Symbol & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Value}\\
        Inertia  & $J_M$ & 0.6 & \kilogram\m\squared\\
        Inertia  & $J_M$ & 0.6 & \kilogram\m\squared\\
        Inertia  & $J_M$ & 0 & \kilogram\m\squared\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic question: how can I, for example, disable the alignment of the first number `0.6` with the other numbers and manually align it right/center/left according to the column margins?

Comment: @Diaa you could use `\multicolumn{1}{<align>}{0.6}` or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

For a simple solution, taking into account the last specifications, I would suggest for a simple solution to add a fixed width (2ex) empty column between the 1st and 2nd column. I've  purposely added two (temporary) vertical rules to help visualise the width of this empty column:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx, siunitx, multicol, ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\Centering}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedLeft}X}

\begin{document}

   \rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
            >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}L|@{}p{2ex}@{}|
            >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}Y
            S[table-format=3.1, round-precision=1, table-column-width = 0.2\linewidth, table-number-alignment=right]%
            s[table-unit-alignment = left, table-column-width = 0.2\linewidth]
        }
        Parameter & & Symbol & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Value}\\
        Inertia & & $J_M$ & 0.6 & \kilogram\m\squared\\
        Inertia & & $J_M$ & 0.6 & \kilogram\m\squared\\
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your patience. It is exactly what I need. I am very frustrated that `\hspace` didn't work with me `:)`. Thanks again

Comment: I have another idea. I'll test it and add it as another solution if it works (the time to check for possible side effects).

Comment: The problem is that whereas `\rowcolor` can take two optional arguments for the colour overhangs, it doesn't work with `\rowcolors` . So tere is a soltion if you do all your coloured rows individually.

Comment: So, should this be reported to the package maintainer?

Comment: Yes, why not? I looked at the code and  didn't see how to patch the command to add these optional arguments (which  only means it's too complex for me).

Comment: I noticed something: does `\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{}` mean start coloring `gray!20` from the second row? If yes, why does it start from the first row? Do I miss something? O is it a valid question?

Comment: Not quite: it means starting the colouring scheme from the 2nd tow, but even colours are in the last argument (no colour) . However, the grey colouring in the first row shouldn't happen, but I don't see why at the moment.

Comment: I found the coloring issue is solved by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297357/2288).

Comment: I see. Very interesting – and subtle. Thank you for informing me!